# Execute nginx reload in all container docker swarm cluster

Tags: docker, nginx, cluster-computing, reload, swarm

We are using Nginx in a docker swarm cluster with 3 managers and 2 workers. When we create new docker service we are executing this:

```
  id=$(docker ps -qf "name=nginx"); docker exec -t $id nginx -s reload
```

However, we shoul reload nginx containers in all managers and workers manually; so, is there any way to execute this command only in one manager and reload workers and other managers automatically?